# How to add logging 'tags' to stackdriver

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

How does BigQuery or any other Google resource add these 'tags' at the top of the stackdriver log entry?

[image]

I have successfully added labels to my log, but these don't show up as 'tags' at the top. Here is an example of how I'm creating a log:

```
    self._queue.put_nowait({
            'info': info,
            'severity': record.levelname,
            'resource': resource,
            'labels': {'test': 'label'},
            'trace': trace,
            'span_id': span_id,
        })
```

How would I add these tags?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by clicking "Add field to summary line". For example:

[image]

You can find more information in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#custom-fields) about viewing logs and custom fields.